# Tool to generate angular documentation searchable via tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation-generator

I work in a company and we have a lot of projects that are using angularjs. My issue here is that we are around 30 devs and it is quite hard to be aware of all directives/components/services that already exists in some projects and not to create it twice.

I'm searching for a tool that could help me search for my directives/components/services via tags and I think the easiest way would be to write comments that contains theses tags and then generate a documentation that allows me to search for them. More of something that help us verifying that what we want to achieve does not already exixts.

Do you have any ideas of the best way to achieve that ?

Pardon me if such a thing is obvious but I don't know much about documentation tools. [ngDocs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) is not what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use [ngDocs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) or [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/). In that way you will be able to generate a documentation e.g. with [jsdoc helper](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc). For tagging you can use JSDoc `@alias` or just `@name` for example.

Once you installed it via `npm` ust run:

```
jsdoc yourJavaScriptFile.js
```

---

### ngDocs example

#### `<doc:example> tag`

```
<doc:example module="...">
  ...
  <doc:source>
    ...
    <script></script> <!-- Contents will be extracted into a script.js file -->
    ...
    <style></style> <!-- Contents will be extracted into a style.css file -->
    ...
  </doc:source>
  <doc:scenario>
    ...
  </doc:scenario>
</doc:example>
```

Comment: Haha it's you again. Well I don't really unterstand how it works then.

Comment: I provided an simple example. The documentation should guide you. If you have problems with the implementation / execution -> switch back to stackoverflow and create a questions including an simple attemp and codes about your problem. ;)

Comment: I don't know if you unterstood me when I'm talking about tags. I'd like to define my own tags then search the tagged directives with thoses words. Something close to twitter hashtag search maybe. These docs will allow me to do that ?

Comment: Yea i know, you could use JSDoc - http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html to make this work. You could also extend jsdoc with an own tag like `@tag` to make it work for your requirements.